# makefile conditional

Tags: makefile, conditional-statements, rule

```
TOUCHFILE=.touch
NM = meow
.PHONY: extract
extract: $(TOUCHFILE)
$(TOUCHFILE): $(ARCHIVE) Makefile
   ifeq ($(wildcard TOUCHFILE),)
   rm -rf $NM
   touch $(TOUCHFILE)
   else
       @echo "nice going";
```

Shouldnt the above work? first time when I dont have the .touch, it removes the dir and creates .touch. next time I run with extract, it should echo nice going correct? I see everytime make removes the meow directory and does rest of stuff.

Comment: Are you trying to use a *shell* if-then-else, or a *Make* if-then-else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that a Make if-then-else must be terminated with `endif`, and the directives must *not* be preceded by TABs, since they are not commands. (Also note that your wildcard expression is wrong -- it searches for "TOUCHFILE", not ".touch"):

```
$(TOUCHFILE): $(ARCHIVE) Makefile
ifeq ($(wildcard $(TOUCHFILE)),)
    rm -rf $NM
    touch $(TOUCHFILE)
else
    @echo "nice going";
endif
```

Comment: @SreeramRavinoothala: what version of Make are you using?